# MongoDB Atlas error: invalid schema, expected mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, mongodb-atlas

I am running through the [Hello World app tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/mongodb-atlas-appengineflex-nodejs-app) in GCP. And I am getting stuck at the server.js step.

The code of the server.js is as below:

```
'use strict';

const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const http = require('http');
const nconf = require('nconf');
let uri = 'mongodb+srv://my_name:<mypassword>@mydatabase-clr75.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
if (nconf.get('mongoDatabase')) {
  uri = `${uri}/${nconf.get('mongoDatabase')}`;
}
console.log(uri);

mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, (err, db) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  // Create a simple little server.
  http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url === '/_ah/health') {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      });
      res.write('OK');
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    const collection = db.collection('Messages');
    var datetime = new Date();
    const msg = {
      msgDescription: '\nHello World received on ' + datetime
    };

    collection.insert(msg, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }

      // push out a range
      let msglist = '';
      collection.find().toArray((err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
        data.forEach((msg) => {
          msglist += `${msg.msgDescription}; `;
        });

        res.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
res.write('Messages received so far:\n');
        res.end(msglist);
      });
    });
  }).listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
    console.log('started web process');
  });
});
```

I receive the error as below:

> mongodb+srv://my_name:@mydatabase-clr75.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
>   /home/herboratory/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:19
>       throw new Error('invalid schema, expected mongodb');
>       ^ Error: invalid schema, expected mongodb
>       at module.exports (/home/herboratory/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:19:11)
>       at connect (/home/herboratory/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:486:16)
>       at Function.MongoClient.connect (/home/herboratory/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:250:3)
>       at Object. (/home/herboratory/server.js:12:21)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! test@1.0.0 start: `node
>   server.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the
>   test@1.0.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with
>   npm. There is likely additional logging output above. npm ERR! A
>   complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/herboratory/.npm/_logs/2019-06-26T03_58_26_823Z-debug.log

I was wondering it should be the format error after reading some other posts here with the same error line, so I've tried '...', "..." and without any quotation mark but still remain error. Would please guide me where's the error?

Except for the URI, is there anywhere else I also need to modify inside the code? As far as I know from the instruction I just need to insert my own Atlas Connection string.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error. The problem was with setup in mongoDB Atlas and setup in my Application.

**In mongoDB Atlas:**

- Create DATABASE and COLLECTION
- Create Database User
- Add your IP Address (public) in IP Whitelist, Network Access

**Example of my solution:**

File .env

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://jmendoza:your-password@cluster0-7rxkw.mongodb.net/nodeapi?retryWrites=true&w=majority
PORT=3000
```

File app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const { postRoutes } = require('./routes/posts');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

dotenv.config();

// BD
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => console.log('mongoDB, Atlas. Connected'))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));

// Middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(expressValidator());

// Routes
app.use('/api/v1', postRoutes);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`A NodeJS API is listining on port: ${port}`);
});
```

File package.json

```
{
    "name": "node-api",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A NodeJS API",
    "main": "app.js",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "nodemon app.js"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "node",
        "api"
    ],
    "author": "Jonathan Mendoza",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-validator": "^5.3.1",
        "mongoose": "^5.9.7",
        "morgan": "^1.9.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.3"
    }
}
```

Running application (console)

```
jmendoza@jmendoza-ThinkPad-T420:~/IdeaProjects/NodeJS-API-Course/Basic-Node-API$ npm run dev

> node-api@1.0.0 dev /home/jmendoza/IdeaProjects/NodeJS-API-Course/Basic-Node-API
> nodemon app.js

[nodemon] 2.0.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
A NodeJS API is listining on port: 3000
mongoDB, Atlas. Connected
```

NodeJS Version

```
jmendoza@jmendoza-ThinkPad-T420:~/IdeaProjects/NodeJS-API-Course/Basic-Node-API$ node -v
v13.12.0
```

You can see my full code on GitHub:

https://github.com/JonathanM2ndoza/NodeJS-API-Course/tree/master/Basic-Node-API

Comment: Thank you very much! I will keep this as references!

Answer (score 2):

The error `invalid schema, expected mongodb` means that you're using an outdated node driver version. The old driver cannot parse the new `mongodb+srv` URI scheme.

Support for the `mongodb+srv` scheme was added in the node driver version 3.0 in this ticket: [NODE-1145](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1145).

Upgrade your node driver using:

```
$ npm install mongodb
```

and the error should go away.

Comment: Hello, Kevin! Thank you very much for your help! I did modify the version (because of the steps...I am not familiar) so that I can just use "mongodb" instead of "mongodb+srv". Also debug some other things and now it works fine.