# When I want to update data in the mongodb - I get 'invalid schema, expected mongodb'

Tags: node.js, mongodb

There is router, which connects to db. Insert operates as expected. Get-data displays all inserted data, but **update** operates as unexpected. console.log issues :

> "(node:10860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: invalid
>   schema, expected mongodb"

.
I don't update my data. What can I do for updating my data?

index.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
let mongo = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
let objectId = require("mongodb");
let assert = require("assert");

let url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";
/* GET home page. */
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("index");
});
router.get("/get-data", (req, res, next) => {
  let resultArray = [];
  mongo.connect(
    url, { native_parser: true },
    (err, db) => {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      let cursor = db.collection("testdata").find();
      cursor.forEach(
        (doc, err) => {
          assert.equal(null, err);
          resultArray.push(doc);
        }, () => {
          db.close();
          res.render("index", { items: resultArray });
        });
      });
  });
router.post("/insert", (req, res, next) => {
  let item = {
    title: req.body.title,
    content: req.body.content,
    author: req.body.author
  };
  mongo.connect(
    url, { native_parser: true },
(err, db) => {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      db.collection("testdata").insertOne(item, (err, result) => {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log("Item inserted");
        db.close();
      });
    });
    res.redirect("/");
  });

router.post("/update", (req, res, next) => {
  let item = {
    title: req.body.title,
    content: req.body.content,
    author: req.body.author
  };
  let id = req.body.id;

  mongo.connect(
    url,{ native_parser: true },
    (err, db) => {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      db.collection("testdata").updateOne(
        { _id: objectId(id) },
        { $set: item },
        (err, result) => {
          assert.equal(null, err);
          console.log("Item updated");
          db.close();
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: I did a little googling.  Someone else was able to resolve this error by updating their Node driver using
npm install mongodb
Does that resolve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56765007/mongodb-atlas-error-invalid-schema-expected-mongodb

Comment: @LaurenSchaefer, It doesn't decide this problem. I upgrade mongodb module, but I also get error:'(node:12191) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: invalid schema, expected mongodb'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why you are having the error:**

You imported `ObjectId` the wrong way.

**The fix:**

Simply import `ObjectId` like this:

`let objectId = require("mongodb").ObjectID`;

instead of this:

`let objectId = require("mongodb")`